# jquery to replace and update content

Tags: jquery

I'm making calls from managed code to javascript, and would like to display time (passed from managed code),

I've got a function such as:

```
function sometimefunction(sometime) {

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#currenttime').before($('<div class="timeupdate"></div>').html('<h3>Last update: ' + sometime+ '</h3')).remove();          
    })
}
```

Now, this replaces the time, but only on the first call..what I would like to happen is to replace time everytime this function is called...(btw. it's a timer, every second from managed code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are removing the update right after you add it. I don't get your HTML structure but here goes:

```
var someTimeFunc = function(sometime){
    $('#currenttime').innerHTML('<h3>'+ sometime +'</h3>')
}
```

Comment: you forgot [0] $('#currenttime')[0].innerHTML and it needs to be =
such as $('#currenttime')[0].innerHTML = ('<h3>'+ sometime +'</h3>')
But sure, it does the job, so thanks for help. (or hint)

Comment: Sorry. Glad it works in the end :) you could escape the [0] by doing

$('#currenttime').html() rather than innerHTML

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason you are having the problem is because your function is just subscribing to a document load event.

You should be okay if you remove the document.ready call:

```
function sometimefunction(sometime) {
    $('#currenttime').before($('<div class="timeupdate"></div>').html('<h3>Last update: ' + sometime+ '</h3')).remove();
}
```

Additionally, you may be able to use the jquery [replaceWith](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/replaceWith) function instead.

Comment: I've tried removing $(document).ready(function()....
However that didn't help.
I also tried something like this: $('#counterscurrenttime').replaceWith($('<div class="quick-timeupdate">' + currentTime + '</div>')); - the problem with replaceWith that I see now, is that it will work the first time, but once it "replaces" the #counterscurrenttime, the second time it won't be there..it would have to be almost something such as: replaceItself.

Answer (score 0):

document.Ready event gets only called by the browser when all the DOM content has been loaded.

Comment: so what's the solution?
I've tried removing the $(document).ready(function()...
didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

the code `$('#currenttime').before(...).remove()` will remove `#currenttime` from the page every time. that's exactly what you're asking it to do...

so:

```
<div id="currenttime"></div>
```

becomes:

```
<div class="timeupdate"><h3>Last update: 00/00/00 00:00:00<div>
```

when what you probably need to end up on the page is the div with timeupdate class to also have the ID your code is looking for:

```
<div id="currenttime" class="timeupdate"><h3>Last update: 00/00/00 00:00:00</h3><div>
```

see how that solves your problem? the easiest way to get there is to start with this code on the page:

```
<div id="currenttime" class="timeupdate"></div>
```

and just use the `html()` function to replace the contents directly:

```
$('#currenttime').html('<h3>Last update: ' + sometime+ '</h3');
```

no `before()`, no `remove()`, no problem. :)